# Does Go copy() handle no-op copies performantly?

Tags: go

Does the following code copy 30 bytes, returning in O(n) in the general case - or "realize" it doesn't have to, and return in constant time?

```
sliceA := make([]byte, 120)
sliceB := sliceA[0:30]
copy(sliceA, sliceB)
```

I'm using Go 1.6.

Comment: Your question depends on specific Go version as compiler may behave differently. 1.6.2 does nothing special - `copy` will be compiled into regular memory copy call. It will be the same even if you change the second line to `sliceB :=  make([]byte, 120)`